# grails REST API with Spring Security core and CORS plugins not working for OPTIONS http method requests

Tags: angularjs, grails, spring-security, cors

Trying to do cross-domain request [CORS] from AngularJS front-end to Grails 2.3.1 RESTful Service on other server.

AngularJS sends OPTIONS http request first for any cross-domain requests.

To support this, I added following method to my Controller that extends RestfulController

```
static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE", options: "OPTIONS", trace: "TRACE", head: "HEAD"]
    @Secured(value=['permitAll'], httpMethod='OPTIONS')
    def options() {
        log.debug("i am in options method")
        response.setHeader("Allow", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS,TRACE,HEAD")
        return
    }
```

For cURL command bellow, my options() method on my Controller never getting called. curl always gets 301 response.

```
curl -H "Origin: http://example.com" -X OPTIONS --verbose http://localhost:8080/Console/tenants/1/spaces.xml
```

Is this a bug in Spring Security core plugin or am I missing something?

My environment consists, Grails 2.3.1, Spring Security Core and ACL 2.0-RC1 plugins and CORS plugin 1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

That's because the browser checks for cross domain requests before your action. You can do that using a servlet filter, or just use the [CORS Grails plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cors).

Comment: I am using CORS Grails plugin. it works if I send request for static page e.g:  [curl -H "Origin: http://example.com" -X OPTIONS --verbose http://localhost:8080/Console/index.html]  but when I send same OPTIONS request to RestfulController URL e.g: [http://localhost:8080/Console/tenants/1/spaces.xml], it always get 301 response with location to auth url. Not sure if it is caused by RestfulController or Spring Security Core Plugin.

Comment: "not a valid http method"? Seriously? You mean they failed to implement the method right?

Comment: @TobiasHagenbeek my previous answer was incorrect, OPTIONS is valid - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS, hard to remember context of an answer from 2013 :(

Comment: Hehe yes it is, and sadly i read my comment and I could have sounded less like an... :) Glad you still come back after so long though!

Answer (score 0):

using latest CORS Grails plugin solves the problem. It includes a filter that intercept OPTIONS request and provide the response.